# Get user culture, not thread culture

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

When my application starts, it sets its own culture to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but in some places, I want to use localized number formatting according to what the user has set in Windows. How can I do this?
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` only returns the thread's culture which is no longer the user's default.

I'm hoping for a more elegant way than storing the thread's default culture before changing it or creating a new thread just to read the culture out of it.

Maybe there's a built-in .Net wrapper for the Windows function `GetUserDefaultLocaleName`?

Comment: Why don't you just save it before you change it?  Nothing that `static` can't do, easy peasy.  Starting a new thread can't work, that was fixed in .NET 4.6.  Something to be concerned about of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo` has an internal property named [`UserDefaultCulture`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,3ba66495ea223b26) which is the equivalence of the Win32 `GetUserDefaultLCID()` as commented in .NET Source code:

> ```
> //
> // This is the equivalence of the Win32 GetUserDefaultLCID()
> //
> internal static CultureInfo UserDefaultCulture
> ```

So you can use it to get user default culture this way:

```
var property = typeof(System.Globalization.CultureInfo).GetProperty("UserDefaultCulture",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var culture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)property.GetValue(null);
```

Also as another option, you can create a new thread and use its `CurrentCulture` property:

```
var culture = new System.Threading.Thread(() => { }).CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: The solution has been tested by .Net 4.6 as well and it works properly.

Comment: In website application `(System.Globalization.CultureInfo)property.GetValue(null);` throws `NullReferenceException`